# ubuntu 10.04 logs itself out overnight

Tags: display, ubuntu-10.04, logout

Every night when I leave work, I lock the screen via ubuntu's "power" button in the top right hand panel.

When I come to work in the morning, I'm greeted with the log-in screen. This doesn't happen every night, but most.

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 on a Dell inspiron. I've included some HW specs, and also dmesg output. Please let me know what other logs may be useful.

thanks!
Corey

```
~$ dmesg 
[20559.696062] type=1503 audit(1285957687.048:16):  operation="open" pid=6212 parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" requested_mask="::r" denied_mask="::r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0 name="/usr/local/lib/libltdl.so.7.2.2"
[21127.951621] type=1503 audit(1285958255.300:17):  operation="open" pid=6390 parent=1 profile="/usr/bin/evince" requested_mask="::r" denied_mask="::r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0 name="/usr/local/lib/libltdl.so.7.2.2"
[291038.528014] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
[291038.528025] render error detected, EIR: 0x00000000
[291038.528042] [drm:i915_do_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_do_wait_request returns -5 (awaiting 22973891 at 22973890)
[291038.828014] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
[291038.828023] render error detected, EIR: 0x00000000
[291038.828042] [drm:i915_do_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_do_wait_request returns -5 (awaiting 22973894 at 22973890)


~$ lspci -vv                                                                                                                           
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
    Kernel modules: intel-agp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 27
    Region 0: Memory at fe400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at dc00 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at feaf8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: 80000000-801fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080200000-00000000803fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA+ VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: feb00000-febfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fdf00000-00000000fdffffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA+ VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
    Region 4: I/O ports at d880 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 19
    Region 4: I/O ports at d800 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 18
    Region 4: I/O ports at d480 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 16
    Region 4: I/O ports at d400 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
    Region 0: Memory at feaf7c00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1) (prog-if 01)
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=32
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA+ VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt, intel-rng

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: I/O ports at d080 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at d000 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at cc00 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at c880 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at c800 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 5
    Region 4: I/O ports at 0400 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02e1
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 26
    Region 0: I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at fdfff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at fdfe0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at febe0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

log$ tail -n 15 Xorg.0.log.old 
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

(II) Power Button: Close
(II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
(II) Power Button: Close
(II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
(II) USB Optical Mouse: Close
(II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
(II) Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Close
(II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
(II) Macintosh mouse button emulation: Close
(II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

Comment: I think this should be in superuser.com

Comment: Just checking, its not power/inactivity settings?

Comment: http://bugs.launchpad.net is the place for this. You and many other people have seen the same root cause. e.g. http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/507504

Answer (score 0):

@msw : That doesn't appear to be the same bug. I have experienced no freezing or locking up. I have not needed to reboot or power cycle my machine.

@Tim : the only power settings I have available are "put the display to sleep in XX minutes". I've disabled it completely, and it has made it two nights without logging me out. Maybe putting the display to sleep causes xorg to crash. I'll report back if I see the bug pop up again.

Comment: You can comment on answers & comments, no need to answer your own question like this.